# How to combine 2 oracle queries with differrent where clauseses into 1 query

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have below 2 oracle queries with different where conditions 
(Some criteria in where condition is same). Is it possible to combine these 2 queries to 1 query?
queries are here

Different conditions: `TX_TYPE, TX_STATUS`

Common conditions: `SUBSCRIBER_ID, MERCHANT_ID, IS_TAXABLE, TX_DATE`

**Query1:**

```
select sum(t.AMOUNT) Amt1
  from RS_TRANSACTION_LOG t, RS_MERCHANT m
 where t.SUBSCRIBER_ID = 11338329
   and t.MERCHANT_ID = m.MERCHANT_ID
   and t.TX_TYPE = '1'
   and t.TX_STATUS in (5, 42)
   and m.IS_TAXABLE = 'Y'
   and TX_DATE between to_date('11/01/2015 00:00:00','MM/dd/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                   and to_date('11/30/2015 23:59:59','MM/dd/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

**Query2:**

```
select sum(t.AMOUNT) Amt2
  from RS_TRANSACTION_LOG t, RS_MERCHANT m
 where t.SUBSCRIBER_ID = 11338329
   and t.MERCHANT_ID = m.MERCHANT_ID
   and t.TX_TYPE = '5'
   and t.TX_STATUS = 5
   and m.IS_TAXABLE = 'Y'
   and TX_DATE between to_date('11/01/2015 00:00:00','MM/dd/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                   and to_date('11/30/2015 23:59:59','MM/dd/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using an `OR` to combine the conditions and `CASE` to separate the amounts:

```
select sum(case when t.TX_TYPE = '1' and t.TX_STATUS in (5,42) then t.AMOUNT else 0 end) Amt1,
       sum(case when t.TX_TYPE = '5' and t.TX_STATUS = 5 then t.AMOUNT else 0 end) Amt2
from   RS_TRANSACTION_LOG t,
       RS_MERCHANT m
where  t.SUBSCRIBER_ID=11338329
and    t.MERCHANT_ID=m.MERCHANT_ID
and    ((t.TX_TYPE = '1' and t.TX_STATUS in (5,42)) or
        (t.TX_TYPE='5' and t.TX_STATUS = '5'))
and    m.IS_TAXABLE='Y'
and    TX_DATE between
       to_date('11/01/2015 00:00:00','MM/dd/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and
       to_date('11/30/2015 23:59:59','MM/dd/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: Seems my question misleads, I want separate amt1 with satisfying these conditions only, t.TX_TYPE='1' and t.TX_STATUS in(5,42) AND amt2 with below conditions only t.TX_TYPE='5' and t.TX_STATUS=5 (And not mixing sum amounts)

Comment: You could add the condition to the column values.